# How do I remove a line that does not contain a specific character?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

For example, I want do remove all lines in a textile that do not contain the character '@'

I have already tried to use sed like so

```
sed '/@/!d' data.txt
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't this work?

Comment: I guess you missed the `-i`: `sed -i '' '/@/!d' data.txt`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! works perfectly.

Comment: I don't think the [tag:bash] tag is relevant, or is it?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `ed` over the non-standard `sed -i`, especially if it needs to be portable:

```
printf "%s\n" "v/@/d" w | ed -s filename
```

This deletes every line that doesn't contain a @, and saves the changed file back to disc.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/@/p' [file]
```

- `-n` suppress default printing
- `/@/` match on `@` anywhere on the line
- `p` print if it matches

Add `-i` for in-place editing of the file (if supplied).